# Creating a grey space between the header view and the first cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create a grey space between the header view (with the two buttons) and the dynamic tableview as shown here:

[image]

This is what I was able to create so far:

[image]

Now there is a line between the header view and the dynamic table view. However, I would like to have a grey space as shown in the picture above. I tried using `Grouped` instead of `Plain`. And I hypothesize that this is a way to achieve my goal because it does add grey to my view like so but only at the bottom:

[image]

So I figured if I can add some padding unto my headerview, that cause the grey to show since I think the background is grey now. So I tried writing some code:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let headerView = taskListTableView.tableHeaderView

    headerView!.setNeedsLayout()
    headerView!.layoutIfNeeded()
    let cGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    let cGHeight = CGSize.init(width: 0, height: 10)
    var frame = headerView!.frame
    headerView!.bounds = CGRect(origin: cGpoint, size: cGHeight)

    frame.size.height = CGFloat(30.0)
    headerView!.frame = frame

    taskListTableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
}
```

But this code is won't compile. Am I on the right track? What else could I do to achieve this effect?

Comment: create one custom view with extra space whatever you want and add that view in you header view.